# Mandrill speed with PHPMailer was fast, now slow, why?

Tags: performance, phpmailer, mandrill

I'm using PHPMailer to send customized emails. The PHP script sends the email and then records the time each email is sent in a text file. On 12/18/14 the speed for sending was an average of 441 emails per minute, which is about the speed since I started using Mandrill a few days before that. But on 12/19/14 it was significantly slower at 25 emails per minute and has been that slow every day since then as well. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have keepalive enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending your emails via SMTP? I also use Mandrill with PHPMailer and saw how the sending speed using SMPT was significantly slower.

You can read all about it here [Mandrill Blog: Making SMTP fast](http://blog.mandrill.com/making-smtp-fast.html)